# Remove outline from select box in FF

Tags: html, css, firefox, xhtml

Is it possible to remove the dotted line surrounding a selected item in a select element?

[image]

I have tried to add the `outline` property in CSS but it did not work, at least not in FF.

```
<style>
   select { outline:none; }
</style>
```

**Update**
Before you go ahead and remove the outline, please read this.
http://www.outlinenone.com/

Comment: three months ago, I searched for the same thing but with a radio button. Over five or six different solutions I've found, nothing worked. So I suspect you cannot do that. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid that is the fact too, but still hope to be proven wrong :D

Comment: Are there actually human beings working at mozilla who think that stupid dotted line looks good?  Why is this even something we have to remove?

Comment: Similar problem with an empty <select multiple>: https://imgur.com/a/oZMttVe

Comment: And for the record, not a single answer here fixes it. :P

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I found a solution, but it is mother of all hacks, hopefully it will serve as a starting point for other more robust solutions. The downside (too big in my opinion) is that any browser that doesn't support `text-shadow` but supports `rgba` (IE 9) won't render the text unless you use a library such as Modernizr (not tested, just a theory).

Firefox uses the text color to determine the color of the dotted border. So say if you do...

```
select {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Firefox will render the dotted border transparent. But of course your text will be transparent too! So we must somehow display the text. `text-shadow` comes to the rescue:

```
select {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

We put a text shadow with no offset and no blur, so that replaces the text. Of course older browser don't understand anything of this, so we must provide a fallback for the color:

```
select {
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

This is when IE9 comes into play: it supports `rgba` but not text-shadow, so you will get an apparently empty select box. Get your version of Modernizr with `text-shadow` detection and do...

```
.no-textshadow select {
  color: #000;
}
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll give it a try sometime soon :)

Comment: The only solution that actually works (using FF 20). Congratulations!

Comment: This should take care of every FF and only FF: `@-moz-document url-prefix()
{
 ::-moz-focus-inner {border: none}
 select:-moz-focusring
 {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
 }
}`

Comment: Will it effect the css in chrome and other browsers?

Answer (score 165):

Well, [Duopixel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11603104/1251219) is plain perfect. If we go a step further we can make it bulletproof.

```
select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

Only valid for Firefox and the ugly dotted outline around the selected option is gone.

Comment: Interestingly, this solution isn't quite a bulletproof as Duopixel’s answer. If you use a transition effect with your select box (i.e. -moz-transition), the dotted box will appear for the duration of the transition, then disappear. So i.e. if you specify '-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;', you will see the combobox for half a second with this solution, whereas you wouldn't see it at all with Duopixel’s answer. You can workaround this by setting the entire select element to have a transparent color attribute, but then you won't see any text at all when the box doesn't have focus.

Comment: Edit: the above should say, "...you will see the *dotted box* for half a second with this solution...". I can't edit the comment anymore.

Anyway, the 'color: rgba(0,0,0,0);' property is what fixes the transition, and it *must* be in the select element; '-moz-focusring' won't do. Also interestingly, for some reason I don't have any issues whatsoever in both IE9 and Chrome with Duopixel's solution, so that stuff at the end he was talking about with Modernizr was completely unnecessary for me.

Comment: Of course it will appear if you specify a transition. Using `all` within transitions is like firing with a Gatling gun on a fly.

Comment: This or Duopixel's solution doesn't work in FF 33.0.3 in Mac Mavericks. Instead of dotted outline, there is a blue blurred outline.

Comment: ha ha ha ha ha, Now this is "mother of hacks"

Comment: Surely, the dotted border has `currentColor` as its border colour set, which is why this works. So if now we can somehow target that dotted border directly, we wouldn't have to **redefine the text colour** which isn't DRY.

Comment: this breaks browser styles on disabled options - once the select in focussed they become black instead of the greyed out text they should be.

Comment: To get rid of the inner focus ring (which surrounds the text of the selected option on a focused `select` even when `-moz-appearance: none;` is in effect), see @Wayne Dunkley's answer below (the missing piece is `select::-moz-focus-inner`).

Answer (score 20):

Here is a collaboration of solutions to fix styling issues with Firefox select boxes. Use this CSS selector as part of your usual CSS reset.

Class removes outline as per question but also removes any background image (as I usually use a custom dropdown arrow and Firefoxes system dropdown arrow can't currently be removed). If using background image for anything other than dropdown image, simply remove line `background-image: none !important;`

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select, select:-moz-focusring, select::-moz-focus-inner {
       color: transparent !important;
       text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000 !important;
       background-image: none !important;
       border:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to still define option text color using this method?

Comment: Actually you can remove Firefox arrows used in the SELECT background, by setting the vendor-specific property `-moz-appearance` to `none`.

Comment: Other answers lack the important `select::-moz-focus-inner` selector, rendering them less effective. That's why this one gets my ⬆.

Comment: `select:-moz-focusring` along with `color: transparent` and `text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000` removed the annoying border on focus in Firefox v63

Comment: Note: url-prefix(). https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2018/moz-document-support-has-been-dropped-except-for-empty-url-prefix/ Reading the links I do not find it clear if they are going to phase it out or not. But be advised.

Answer (score 9):

In general, form controls are impossible to style to that degree of accuracy. There's no browser I'm aware of that supports a sensible range of properties in all controls. That's the reason why there're a gazillion JavaScript libraries that "fake" form controls with images and other HTML elements and emulate their original functionality with code:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

...

Comment: Thx, I guess I have to "make my own" select list to accomplish this. Too bad that form controls isn't more uniform across browsers.

Comment: @Martin: this is nothing compare to the inflexibility of a file upload control, which cannot be styled *at all* in most browsers. ;)

Answer (score 9):

This will target all firefox versions

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    select {
       color: transparent !important;
       text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000 !important;
    }
}
```

You might want to remove the !important, if you plan to have the outline appear on other pages across your site that use the same stylesheet.

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Answer (score 3):

`<select onchange="this.blur();">`

If you use this the border stays until you select an item from the list.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not respect accessibility and usability guidelines. Besides TTS interfaces for blind users, it disallows keyboard navigation. Focused elements should look different from others, the issue with the current question is that Firefox does not let you decide how.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
a:active {
 outline: none;
 -moz-outline: none;
}

a {
-moz-user-focus: none;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-1801.html)

Comment: Thx for the effort, but unfortunatly it did not work. Maybe it works on a `a` element, but it did not work on a `select` element.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes the solution

```
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```

Comment: Tested. Doesn't work. Firefox recognises this property but it doesn't appear to do anything. Tried setting it to `10px solid red` and I can't find where it shows up.

Comment: This actually worked for me when all other higher voted answers didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Remove outline/dotted border from Firefox All Selectable Tags.

Put this line of code in your style sheet:

```
*:focus{outline:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Add HTML:
Add the select options of your choice and add the attribute: contenteditable="true"

Step 2) Add CSS:
Use the [attribute] selector to select all elements that are contenteditable, and remove the border with the outline property:

```css
[contenteditable] {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
select {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<select contenteditable="true">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

To remove the outline of the select box when selected/focused.

Answer (score 0):

https://ssiddique.info/projects/jqueryplugins/demo/index.php?demo=CheckboxStylized check this out
Download the plugin from [here](https://ssiddique.info/jquery-css-plugins)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Add **border-style: none** to your select in CSS.

```
select {
border-style: none; }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    input[type='range']::-moz-focus-outer {
    border: 0;
    outline: none !important;
    }
```

working 100%

Answer (score -4):

This will remove focus from the `select` element and the *outline*:

```
$("select").click(function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Though this isn't without its shortcomings on other browsers. You'll want to check the browser the user is using:

```
if (FIREFOX) {
    //implement the code
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code snippet does in addition to providing the code snippet.

Comment: `if (FIREFOX) { //implement the code }` BAHAHAHA thanks for a good laugh