# How can I remove the dotted lines on a SELECT/OPTION dropdown control in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, dotted-line

In **Chrome** and other browsers my dropdown looks **fine**:

[image]

However, in **Firefox** it has unwanted **dotted** lines:

[image]

I have successfully removed the unwanted Firefox dotted lines for **buttons** and **input** elements with these CSS statements:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
```

so I thought these would work for the select/option elements, but they don't:

```
select::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
option::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
```

**How can I remove the dotted lines in this dropdown so that it appears as in Chrome and other browsers?**

## Addendum

These don't work either:

```
select::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; outline: 0 }
option::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; outline: 0 }
```

nor these:

```
select { outline: 0; }
option { outline: 0; }
```

nor these:

```
select { outline: none; }
option { outline: none; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove outline from select box in FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773430/remove-outline-from-select-box-in-ff)

Answer (score 9):

James Broad's answer is nearly perfect, but the "shadow-only" text for the option items looks ugly. This is what works perfectly for me:

```
select:-moz-focusring {
  color:transparent;
  text-shadow:0 0 0 #000; /* your normal text color here */
}
select:-moz-focusring * {
  color:#000; /* your normal text color here */
  text-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: If you you are using Bootstrap or have any transitions on your input, don't forget to add  ```transition: color 0ms;```, or else you will see the dotted line fade out.

Answer (score 5):

Here's combined hack for that:

```
select:focus {
    outline: 1px solid white;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
select ~ input[type=button] {
    -moz-appearance: menulist-button;
    margin-left: -19px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Then add input with tabindex=0 after each select
And some code for focus "delegation":

```
$("select ~ input[type=button]").addEvent('focus', function(){
  this.getPrevious().focus();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work after 2 years on another platform (I tried on WinXP and recent FF version for that time), is it? I consider it is ok for hacks...
Thanks for information anyway.

Answer (score 4):

the solution found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853002/728855 seems to work perfectly.

In short:

```
select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

Where #000 is your text colour.

Comment: This won't work when building a reusable component - you can't know the text colour there. It has to be inherited, and because you're setting `color`, the `currentColor` property can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using with `required`, like the code below:

```
<select required="true">
    <option value="" selected="true" disabled="true" hidden="true">Select a Option</option>
    <option value="">Option</option>
</select>
```

You will need set the same parameters for `select:required:invalid` like below:

```
select {
  &:required {
    &:invalid {
      color: transparent;
      text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    }
  }

  &:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

try using `outline: 0,` works for buttons

Comment: I tried those (see above) but it didn't seem to remove the dotted line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773430/remove-outline-from-select-box-in-ff  seems it was already discussed here