# How I can remove annoying dotted frame from select/option element in the Mozilla Firefox browser?

Tags: select, screenshot, frame

Please help!

I have those annoying dotted frame in Mozilla Firefox 68.7.0esr (64).

I've tried all known methods for removing this frame. For example I've tested all of answers here
[How can I remove the dotted lines on a SELECT/OPTION dropdown control in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913409/how-can-i-remove-the-dotted-lines-on-a-select-option-dropdown-control-in-firefox)

[Existing methods here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913409/how-can-i-remove-the-dotted-lines-on-a-select-option-dropdown-control-in-firefox)

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51b5I.jpg)

[This is the site URL](https://ra-solo.com.ua/portfolio/html)

Please view the site with the the narrow page so the mobile menu (select/option) was activated.

Thank you all beforehand!

Comment: So you tried `::-moz-focus-inner` and it didn’t work? Can you show the CSS you tried?

Comment: Certainly I tried this many times

This is the style.css
https://ra-solo.com.ua/css/style.css
select::-moz-focus-inner,
option::-moz-focus-inner,
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none !important;
}