# select/option html tag dotted outline problem in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

`button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }` works for buttons...

what about for `select`/`option` html tag?

i try everything what is here:
[How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

but i open new question becouse there is talking about buttons...

Comment: How are non-pointer users supposed to know where they are about to 'click' if you hide the focus ring?

Comment: It does not have to be a black dotted ring, does it? It could be, for example, a distinct background or a different font color. If people want to mess with enforced defaults -- they can find a way to do it (e.g. use javascript to simulate <select> elements with something else).

Comment: @Quentin, there are other ways to show the user where focus is without these built-in (and in my opinion, ugly) styles. Users can easily apply rules to `:focus` and/or `:active` pseudo-classes.

Comment: @Philip Walton — There are, but how many authors who remove the default put something else in its place? And users cannot *easily* apply their own rules, most don't even know that they can.

Answer (score 1):

```
  select, option {
        border: 0 none;
        outline: 1px none;
    }
```

always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
select, option {outline:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Firefox 11.0 the dotted outline around the select, option and button elements no longer exists, as far as I can tell by tests performed under **Win7 with FF 11.0**, and under **Ubuntu 12.04 with FF 12.0**.

Also noticed that around links like does of a Google Search Result Pagination Numbers, the dotted outline does not appear for the same versions of Firefox.

Seems to be an issue being dealt with by the Mozilla Firefox.

Made this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/s4Gtn/) to test it!

Answer (score 0):

```
select:-moz-focusring { color: transparent; }
```

This works. It's weird becuase the element you're seeing is `:-moz-focusring` but even if you use `outline` or `border` properties overwriting, the dotted line won't dissapear. Since the dotted line color depends on the color of the `select`, you can use this pseudo selector to put a transparent color (and make it invisible) but still have the original color in the select box text.

Comment: Bad notice: it makes the label invisible on focus. CRAP!

Comment: With some work, this is THE solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853002/1251219

Comment: Makes the whole text disappear on my FF 25, windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    select, option {
        border: 0 none;
        outline: 1px none;
    }
```