# Remove dotted border/outline of focused dropdown menu

Tags: css

How do you remove the dotted border/outline that is shown when selecting an item from a dropdown menu?

[image]

You can see there is a dotted border/outline shown, I want to remove this (screenshot taken in Firefox).

Trying the solution below did not remove it:

```
select:focus, option:focus, select::-moz-focus-inner, option::-moz-focus-inner {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

The HTML is just simply this:

```
<select name="order">
   <option value="desc">Newest to oldest</option>
   <option value="asc">Oldest to newest</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you pass on the HTML markup as well.

Comment: I tried in Firefox on Windows 7 and there is no dotted border.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove outline from select box in FF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773430/remove-outline-from-select-box-in-ff)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On windows 7 and IE9 no border/outline is shown, Instead a blue background is shown. The blue background and in your case the border/outline is managed by the OS. I suspect your are on a Mac?

[Remove outline from select box in FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773430/remove-outline-from-select-box-in-ff)

[How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

Answer (score 16):

Add the following to your stylesheet.   -

```
select:-moz-focusring { color: transparent;
                        text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000; }
```

Has always worked for me, hope it helps!

Comment: Not sure if this is the best solution, but it's interesting.

Comment: Agreed, not sure it's the 'best', but it has been solid and works brilliantly for me. Any other suggestions would be great as well.

Comment: This solution make all options transparent.