# Cannot remove outline/dotted border from Firefox select drop down

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a styled down down, but I cannot remove the dotted border when it is clicked in **Firefox**. I've used `outline: none` but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

**CSS:**

```
.styled-select {
    background: lightblue;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: 0 none !important;
    outline: 1px none !important;
}
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-appearance: none;       
   text-indent: 0.01px;
   text-overflow: '';
   border: 0 none !important;
   outline: 1px none !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <select id="select">
        <option value="0">Option one</option>
        <option value="1">Another option</option>
        <option value="2">Select this</option>
        <option value="3">Something good</option>
        <option value="4">Something bad</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtVGg/).

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself.**

Comment: Works. Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Looked fine in Chrome. Firefox showed a gap between the "Select this" and the dropdown itself. I'm on a corporate computer and stuck with IE8, so Fiddler didn't even come up in IE. LOL!

Comment: Apologies @FreshPrinceOfSO, I've now added the code.

Comment: @NathanLee, I've cleared my cache but I still see the dotted border

Comment: It's to do with firefox.

Refer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119629/remove-dotted-border-outline-of-focused-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853002/1261316

It wasn't set as the correct answer, but it worked perfectly for me:

```
select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
select {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: (!) this also makes the color of the list items transparent

Comment: tx, works for me (options are visible in FF 29 OSX)

Comment: Grate , does what it should do , thanks . FF ubuntu 14 lts

Comment: If you you are using Bootstrap or have any transitions on your input, don't forget to add  ```transition: color 0ms;```, or else you will see the dotted line fade out at the moment you focus on the select box!

Comment: @Simon: you're right, it does. I found that the best way to avoid that is to use two additional rules: `option { text-shadow: none }` to undo the shadow effect, and `option:not(:checked) { color: #000; }` - *or whatever the normal text color is* - to reset the color. *Not checked*, because the selected option should get its color and background from the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: @shrewdbeans Thanks for sharing, it's solve my issue to :)

Answer (score -2):

This will help you. Place it on top of your style sheet.

```
/**
* Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
*/

a:focus {
    outline:0;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: What about a `Firefox select drop down` like asked in the question?

Comment: It works with my bootstrap selectpicker. Thank you