# The select element inner border in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

The select element still gets an inner border on focus. Here's a sample form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<select>
  <option value="first">First option</option>
  <option value="second">Second option</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I remove it?

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: so what your question about??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove outline from select box in FF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773430/remove-outline-from-select-box-in-ff)

Answer (score 0):

The border is there as a user-facing feature so the user can see what's focused.  You can't remove it.