# How do I get rid of <select> element outline in Firefox?

Tags: html, css

So here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/CVTrb/1/, click and select on any option, and then you should see a thin gray line appear that doesn't exactly sit within the `<select>` element.

Here's an image demonstrating this:

[image: Here's an image demonstrating this]:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credit to this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853002/1261316

```
select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `outline: none;` to `.form-dropdown`

Comment: For some reason this solution did not work, @DrydenLong's did though. This is why I selected his answer FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add a tweak:
If you've got disabled options, that text-shadow kinda uglifies them

```
select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;  /* hides that darn border... and the options */
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;   /* "unhide" the options */
}
select:-moz-focusring option:disabled {
    text-shadow: none;     /* remove the inherited shadow from disabled options */
}
```