# Input select look and feel on foucs in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I see a extra dotted line for input select on focus in firefox not for other browsers, just wondering is there any quick work around for it? attached screenshot below, it usually goes away after licking other places in browser.

[image: input select glitch]

Comment: Try CSS for `select:focus` or `option:focus`.

Comment: People navigating your site with the keyboard will need some indicator that the select dropdown got the focus so if you do figure out how to remove it, you should still add some visual indication when it gets focus.

Comment: @mplungjan - Doesn't seem to work with the select tag.

Comment: Probably the [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property.

Comment: @Barmar, that would select the entire select box. And there is nothing around the select when I made one in firefox. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/ecz5m8jj/)

Comment: You'll probably want [Fleshgrinder's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853002/4076315) instead of the currently accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (hack) (based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11603104/1236396)

```
select {
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

or this one (based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853002/1236396)

```
select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Does this work: `select::-moz-focus-inner {  border: 0; }`?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.