# how to make link inside of submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So for a website I am making, I made a contact me page and have a contact me form. I want to make a button that makes the user think that they have submitted the form (this is a school project and i am restricted to html, css and javascript) by taking the user to another page. I have it partially working as it only works when the button is blurred. I want it to work when the button is unblurred. Here is my code for the page:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('.my-form input[id="terms"]');
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".my-form button");
const image = document.querySelector('.image');
const hover = document.querySelector('.hover');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const close = document.querySelector('.close');

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {

  const checked = this.checked;
  for (const btn of btns) {
    checked ? (btn.disabled = false) : (btn.disabled = true);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700");

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 125.19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* Links inside the navbar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;

  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 126.4px;
  background-color: inherit;

}

.box {
  width: 1100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border : 5px solid #000000;
  margin: 10;


}
/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 126.4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700");

/* RESET RULES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
:root {
  --white: #afafaf;
  --red: #e31b23;
  --bodyColor: #292a2b;
  --borderFormEls: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
  --bgFormEls: hsl(0, 0%, 14%);
  --bgFormElsFocus: hsl(0, 7%, 20%);
}

/* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}
*/
input,
select,
textarea,
button {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}

button,
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

select {
  appearance: none;
}

/* Remove native arrow on IE */
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove dotted outline from selected option on Firefox*/
/*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773430/remove-outline-from-select-box-in-ff/18853002#18853002*/
/*We use !important to override the color set for the select on line 99*/
select:-moz-focusring {
  color: transparent !important;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 var(--white);
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  font: 18px/1.5 "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background: var(--bodyColor);
  color: var(--white);
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}


/* FORM ELEMENTS
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.my-form h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.my-form li,
.my-form .grid > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.my-form select,
.my-form input,
.my-form textarea,
.my-form button {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border: 1px solid var(--borderFormEls);
  color: var(--white);
  background: var(--bgFormEls);
  transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.21, 0.69, 1.25),
    transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.21, 0.69, 1.25);
}

.my-form textarea {
  height: 170px;
}

.my-form ::placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  /*Fix opacity issue on Firefox*/
  opacity: 1;
}

.my-form select:focus,
.my-form input:focus,
.my-form textarea:focus,
.my-form button:enabled:hover,
.my-form button:focus,
.my-form input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label {
  background: var(--bgFormElsFocus);
}

.my-form select:focus,
.my-form input:focus,
.my-form textarea:focus {
  transform: scale(1.02);
}

.my-form *:required,
.my-form select {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right 12px;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
}

.my-form *:required {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/asterisk.svg);
}

.my-form select {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/down.svg);
}

.my-form *:disabled {
  cursor: default;
  filter: blur(2px);
}


/* FORM BTNS
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.my-form .required-msg {
  display: none;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/asterisk.svg)
    no-repeat center left / 15px 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.my-form .btn-grid {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: filter 0.2s;
}

.my-form button {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.my-form button > * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.my-form button .back {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-110%, -50%);
}

.my-form button:enabled:hover .back,
.my-form button:focus .back {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.my-form button:enabled:hover .front,
.my-form button:focus .front {
  transform: translateX(110%);
}


/* CUSTOM CHECKBOX
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.my-form input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.my-form input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.21, 0.69, 1.25);
}

.my-form input[type="checkbox"] + label::before,
.my-form input[type="checkbox"] + label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.my-form input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 6px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 2px solid var(--white);
}

.my-form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background: var(--red);
}

.my-form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 14px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--white);
  border-right: 2px solid var(--white);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}


/* FOOTER
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
footer {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer span {
  color: var(--red);
}


/* MQ
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .my-form .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1.5rem;
  }

  .my-form .grid-2 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }

  .my-form .grid-3 {
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .my-form .grid > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .my-form .required-msg {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 541px) {
  .my-form input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .my-form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    top: 3px;
  }
}
.container{
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.ul2{
  display: flex;


}
.ul2 li{
  display: flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
  position: relative;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: #171515;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}
.ul2 li:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  /* background: #d35400; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(.9);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(1):before{
  background: #4267B2;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(2):before{
  background: #1DA1F2;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(3):before{
  background: #E1306C;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(4):before{
  background: #2867B2;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(5):before{
  background: #ff0000;
}
.ul2 li:hover:before{
  filter: blur(3px);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 15px #d35400; */
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(1):hover:before{
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #4267B2;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(2):hover:before{
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #1DA1F2;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(3):hover:before{
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #E1306C;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(4):hover:before{
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2867B2;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(5):hover:before{
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0000;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(1):hover{
  color: #456cba;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #4267B2;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #4267B2;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(2):hover{
  color: #26a4f2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #1DA1F2;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #1DA1F2;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(3):hover{
  color: #e23670;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #E1306C;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #E1306C;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(4):hover{
  color: #2a6cbb;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2867B2;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #2867B2;
}
.ul2 li:nth-child(5):hover{
  color: #ff1a1a;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0000;
}
.ul2 li:hover{
  color: #ffa502;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #d35400;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #d35400;
}
.con{
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;

}
.fatness{
  float: right;
}
.epic{
  float: left;
}
.con2{
  float: right;
}
.con:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.con .image{
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.con:hover .image{
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
.image img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
.con:hover .image img{
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.con:hover .image{
 transform: translateY(-100px);
}

.con:hover > ul > li > a{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.con:hover > ul > li:nth-child(2) a{
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.con:hover > ul > li:nth-child(3) a{
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.con:hover > ul > li:nth-child(4) a{
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.con:hover > ul > li:nth-child(5) a{
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.con .content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.info{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 26px;
}
.info h2{
  font-size: 27px;
  margin: 3px 0;
}
.info span{
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.https{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.https :visited{
text-decoration: none;
color: #69655b;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link href="AboutUs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<head>
<img src="Images/FinalLogo.jpg" width="106" height="106">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact Us Page</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cutive+Mono&family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">                          also this
</head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="ISTwebsite.html">Home</a>
    <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Stories
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Jack and Jill</a>
        <a href="Cinderalla.html">Cinderella</a>
        <a href="#">Snow White</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="ContactUsPage.html" class="active" >Contact Us</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <body style="background-color:#faecca">
        <form class="my-form">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Get in touch!</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <select>
                  <option selected disabled>-- Please choose an option --</option>
                  <option>Send feedback</option>
                  <option>Want to collab</option>
                  <option>Other</option>
                </select>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="grid grid-2">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" required>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="grid grid-2">
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                  <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone">
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="terms">
                <label for="terms">I have read and agreed with <a href="">the terms and conditions.</a></label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="grid grid-3">
                  <div class="required-msg">REQUIRED FIELDS</div>
                  <button class="btn-grid" type="submit" disabled>
                    <span class="back">
                     <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/email-icon.svg" alt="">
                    </span>
                                <div class="https">
                    <span class="front"><a href="ContactUsPageAfter.html" style="text-decoration:none">SUBMIT</a></span>
</div>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn-grid" type="reset" disabled>
                    <span class="back">
                      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/eraser-icon.svg" alt="">
                    </span>
                    <span class="front">RESET</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </form>
<div class="epic">
        <div class="con">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="Images/blankprofile.png">
      </div>
<div class="content">
        <div class="info">
          <h2>
Name</h2>
<span>Student</span>
        </div>
</div>

</div>
        <ul class="ul2" >
<li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
<li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
<li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
<li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
<li><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="fatness">
        <div class="con">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="Images/blankprofile.png">
      </div>
<div class="content">
        <div class="info">
          <h2>
Name</h2>
<span>Student</span>
        </div>
</div>

</div>
        <ul class="ul2" >
<li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
<li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
<li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
<li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
<li><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></li>
</ul>
</div>

  </body>
    <script src="ContactUsPage.js"></script>

</html>
```

when I press the submit button, it just reloads the page on my local desktop. Could someone help me make the submit button work?

Comment: If you just want to link to another page rather than submitting a form, why not just use a link and style it like a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using links in `<button>` element. What you should do is add **action** attribute to your `<form>`

So in your case what you should do is change:

`<form class="my-form">`

to

`<form class="my-form" action="ContactUsPageAfter.html">`

and also change:

`<span class="front"><a href="ContactUsPageAfter.html" style="text-decoration:none">SUBMIT</a></span>`

to:

`<span class="front">SUBMIT</span>`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to simulate a submit button but not actually submit anything you can make use of prevent.default in your function call.

check: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

But if you want a different behaviour you could choose a different input type / button and wrap it around a link tag as someone else has already suggested in this thread.